# Hilbert transform analytic signal frequency range

Tags: proof-verification, signal-processing, analytic-functions

> For the real signal $f(t),$ show that if it is band-limited to the
>   range
>
> $$\nu_0 - \frac{1}{2} \alpha \leq \nu \leq \nu_0 + \frac{1}{2}
> > \alpha$$ (where $\nu_0 >\frac{1}{2} \alpha >0$), then the modulus
>   squared of the analytic signal $|f_a (t)|^2$ is band-limited to the
>   frequency range $-\alpha \leq \nu \leq \alpha.$

How should I approach this problem? I am very confused because no explicit expression for $f(t)$ is given, so I don't know how to find $|f(t)|^2$ (the  envelope of $f(t)$ squared).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if $f$ is real and band limited on $[A,B]$ then $f(t) = \int_A^B F(\xi) e^{2 i \pi \xi t} dt$ and $f_a(t) =  \int_A^B (1+sign(\xi)) F(\xi) e^{2 i \pi \xi t} dt = \int_A^B  F_a(\xi) e^{2 i \pi \xi t} dt$, $\overline{f_a(t)} = \int_A^B  \overline{F_a(-\xi)} e^{2 i \pi \xi t} dt$ hence by the convolution theorem $|f_a(t)|^2 =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty H(\xi) e^{2 i \pi \xi t} dt$ with $H(\xi ) = F_a \ast \overline{F_a^{rev}}(\xi) = \int F_a(\nu-\xi) \overline{F_a(\nu)}d\nu$ whose support is $[-(B-A),(B-A)]$

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I have a few questions: what do the superscript $rev$ and the overline in $\bar{f_a}$ represent? Could you also please explain how you deduced that the support of the last expression has to be $\pm(B−A)$? Thank you.

Comment: $F(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_Duality , and $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate, and the support is $[-(B-A),(B-A)]$ because otherwise the integral is $0$.

Comment: I see. What about $F_a^{rev}$? Does that stand for the inverse Fourier transform of $f_a$? Thank you.

Comment: I meant the term $\overline{F^{rev}_a} (\xi)$. Does that mean the complex conjugate of the inverse Fourier transform of $f$? Your link does not use the $rev$ notation, so I'm slightly confused.

Comment: $\overline{F_a^{rev}}(\xi)$ meant the Fourier transform of $\overline{f_a(t)}$. Honestly I don't see why you are confused and ask for such a confirmation. If you are not sure, just re-prove everything. that's why I wrote it in a comment and not in a detailed answer, I wrote it as an hint that you can use for re-proving everything and try to make all this rigorous.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much for your help.